# GCloud SQL from K8s - errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to connect to cloud sql from k8s instance with a side-car proxy running at the same pod.

According to Google guidelines i should reuse Service Account with JSON private key to let pod to access given SQL instance.

With newly created SQL instance i seem automatically get Service Account which looks like: 
`[hash]@speckle-umbrella-pg-8.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

With this account, how can i generate JSON private key? I was trying to create SSL certificate in "Connections" tab, but there is no option to create JSON ones.

As second option i was trying to reuse existing IAM service account - "Compute Engine default service account", having generated JSON key for it, but it did not work.

The way i set it up is:

1. I create a secret `kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-instance-credentials --from-file=credentials.json=[PROXY_KEY_FILE_PATH]`
2. I attache container to the pod:

   `- name: cloudsql-proxy
   image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
   command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
   "-instances=project-name:us-central1:sql-instance-name=tcp:5432",
   "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
   securityContext:
   runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
   allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
   volumeMounts:
       - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
           mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
           readOnly: true`

Whts the correct way? Goole docs does not seem to contain complete information.

Answer (score 0):

1 - In the first option, you may create a JSON private key by following the guidelines mentioned [in this article](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys). Once the key has been generated, you can store it in a directory to create the SSL certificate.

2-  In the second option, we need to know what is the issue you’ve experienced exactly. Please share the error message. The issue here is that the Compute Engine default [service account may or may not have the necessary permissions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform) to use other Cloud Platform APIs. This depends on how your project is configured.